# Cube root of 39304

Tags: elementary-number-theory

To find a cube root of a large number, you only have to memorize the cube roots of numbers 1 to 10.

Take the last digit of your number, it'll be the last digit of the result.

Then ignore the last 3 digits, look at what remains, and find which of the first 10 cubes is the closest to it without going over.

Now put the result together.

Example: $\sqrt[3]{39304} = 34$ because last digit of 39304 is 4 and $3^3 =  27$ is closest cube to 39.

**Why can we ignore the last 3 digits?**

[image]

Comment: Actually, it isn't true. 33^3 = 35937. And you can see that last digits are different.

Comment: FWIW, the image seems to have come from https://brightside.me/inspiration-tips-and-tricks/11-simple-math-hacks-313560/